# Sorting a Vector of Vectors

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I have a vector of vector containing elements of type long as follows:

```
vector< vector<long> > Data(N,vector<long>(M));
```

I have to sort these vectors based on their values i.e. For Two vectors

```
Data[i] & Data[j]
if for some k Data[i][k]< Data[j][k]
and Data[i][t]==Data[j][t] for all 0<=t<=(k-1),
then Data[i] should come before Data[j] in the final vector
```

Not for the above task I wrote the following code:

```
sort(Data.begin(),Data.end(),myfunc);

where

bool myfunc(vector<long> vec1,vector<long> vec2){
     int i=0;
     while(i<vec1.size()){
         if(vec1[i]<vec2[i]){
             return false;
         }
         else if(vec1[i]>vec2[i]){
             return true;
         }
         i++;
     }
     return false;
}
```

However, I am not getting the desired output. In fact the input and output vectors are the same. Where did I go wrong?? Am I missing something??

Comment: the result will be the same, but the function should be `bool myfunc(const vector<long> &vec1,const vector<long>& vec2)`

Comment: I am not sure I follow the desired logic, but what is wrong with a simple call to `std::sort`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple mistakes, but not all are evident to you (yet).

```
bool myfunc(const vector<long>& vec1, const vector<long>& vec2){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec1.size() && i < vec2.size(); i++){
         if(vec1[i] > vec2[i]){
             return false;
         } else if(vec1[i] < vec2[i]){
             return true;
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I took the liberty of using a `for` loop and `size_t`, which are better practices here.

Comment: Thanks...It's working...Checked the documentation for the comparison function and found out that my concepts were wrong. :)
However I still used it as 
bool myfunc(vector<long> vec1,vector<long> vec2) and it is working.
Any concepts I need to further explore??

Comment: And what's with these best practices?? Can you explain a bit further, because I always use a while loop for any task whatsoever.

Comment: What if the vectors are of different size? In the current code both seem to be greater than the other.

Comment: @alphacentauri I can't see how this is different to a simple call to `std::sort` with the default ordering. Either you are over-complicating things, or you need to explain your requirements better.

Comment: By a simple call do you mean without the comparison function?? I tried it...Doesn't work. And I think it shouldn't..since we are dealing with vector of vectors that cannot be implicitly compared.

Comment: @RolandIllig, `a < b` is false and `b < a` is false. Therefore they are *equal* to each other (they can wind up in any order relative to each other). This follows the described sort.

Comment: @alphacentauri, when you are iterating through a collection `for` loop is often used since it is more concise.

Comment: @alphacentauri If you use bool myfunc(vector<long> vec1,vector<long> vec2) the vectors will be copied into the function, which can be slow if the vectors are big as well as being unnecessary. That is why it is recommended to use const reference (const vector<long>& vec1, ...)

Answer (score 1):

I tried implementing your code as is. It appears to sort the vectors in descending order. Try toggling the trues and falses from your myfunc function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool myfunc(vector<long> vec1,vector<long> vec2){
     int i=0;
     while(i<vec1.size()){
         if(vec1[i]<vec2[i]){
             return false;
         }
         else if(vec1[i]>vec2[i]){
             return true;
         }
         i++;
     }
     return false;
}

int main()
{
    int N = 5, M = 5;

    vector< vector<long> > Data(N,vector<long>(M));
    for ( int i = 0; i < Data.size(); i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < Data[i].size(); j++ )
            Data[i][j] = 5-i;

    }

    sort( Data.begin(), Data.end(), myfunc );
    for ( int i = 0; i < Data.size(); i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < Data[i].size(); j++ )
            cout << Data[i][j] << " " ;
        cout << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5 5 5 5 5
4 4 4 4 4
3 3 3 3 3
2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1
```

After toggling the trues and falses, the following code sorts the vectors in correct order.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool myfunc(const vector<long> &vec1, const vector<long> &vec2){
     int i=0;
     while(i<vec1.size()){
         if(vec1[i]<vec2[i]){
             return true;
         }
         else if(vec1[i]>vec2[i]){
             return false;
         }
         i++;
     }
     return true;
}

int main()
{
    int N = 5, M = 5;

    vector< vector<long> > Data(N,vector<long>(M));
    for ( int i = 0; i < Data.size(); i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < Data[i].size(); j++ )
            Data[i][j] = 5-i;

    }

    sort( Data.begin(), Data.end(), myfunc );
    for ( int i = 0; i < Data.size(); i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < Data[i].size(); j++ )
            cout << Data[i][j] << " " ;
        cout << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
```